# how to move next and previous div without using ng-repeat Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create move to next and previous section on click next and previous button . It's working fine. But when i use ng-repeat it's stop working
here is ng-repeat code

```
    <div class="bookaclass_main" ng-controller="NextAndPrev">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row col-md-2-4" ng-class="{'card-hide': index  > $index + 1}" ng-repeat="card in cards" ng-style="{left: 2 ,'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
        <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">b</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">c</div>
  </div>

<div class="keys">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" ng-click="index = index < cards.length ? index + 1 : cards.length">Next</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-pre" ng-click="index = index > 1 ? index - 1 : 1">Previous</button>
    {{index}}
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

here is controller

```
app.controller('NextAndPrev', function($scope) {    
    $scope.cards = [{},{},{}];
    $scope.index = 1;
});
```

It's working fine but when i used static data like this it's animated all div in left side

```
<div class="bookaclass_main" ng-controller="NextAndPrev">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row col-md-2-4" ng-class="{'card-hide': index > $index + 1}" ng-style="{left: 2 ,'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
            <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">b</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">c</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-2-4" ng-class="{'card-hide': index > $index + 1}" ng-style="{left: 2, top: 2 * $index + 'px', 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
            <div class="col-md-4">d</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">e</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">f</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-2-4" ng-class="{'card-hide': index > $index + 1}" ng-style="{left: 2 * $index + 'px', top: 2 * $index + 'px', 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
            <div class="col-md-4">d</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">e</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">f</div>
        </div>
        <div class="keys">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" ng-click="index = index < cards.length ? index + 1 : cards.length">Next</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-pre" ng-click="index = index > 1 ? index - 1 : 1">Previous</button>
            {{index}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
.card-hide {
    left: -100px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
.col-md-2-4 {
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

How to fix the issue please help me out

Comment: isn'it an index issue ? ng-class="{'card-hide': index > $index + 1}" on each of your div could be the issue

Comment: @Groben how to fix that ? what will be the solution for that it's working fine when i use ng-repeat.

Comment: ng-class="{'card-hide': index > 1}" on the first div, ng-class="{'card-hide': index > 2}" on the second, etc. Try to compare the html resulting of the ng-repeat with the static one

Comment: @Groben thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on changing ng-class like below code.

```
<div class="bookaclass_main" ng-controller="NextAndPrev">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row col-md-2-4" ng-class="{'card-hide': index > 1}" ng-style="{left: 2 ,'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
            <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">b</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">c</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-2-4" ng-class="{'card-hide': index > 2}" ng-style="{left: 2, top: 2 * $index + 'px', 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
            <div class="col-md-4">d</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">e</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">f</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-2-4" ng-class="{'card-hide': index > 3}" ng-style="{left: 2 * $index + 'px', top: 2 * $index + 'px', 'z-index': (cards.length - $index)}">
            <div class="col-md-4">d</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">e</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">f</div>
        </div>
        <div class="keys">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" ng-click="index = index < cards.length ? index + 1 : cards.length">Next</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-pre" ng-click="index = index > 1 ? index - 1 : 1">Previous</button>
            {{index}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```